# Best translation for "Quality over quantity"

Tags: перевод, выражения, английский

What is the best translation into Russian of the common English expression "Quality over quantity"?

I have not found any answers on the internet.

(Bear in mind that I'm a native Russian speaker.)

Comment: That's because Stalin purged this concept from Russia in his five year plans.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Лучше меньше, да лучше. ([В. И. Ленин](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5,_%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5))

Comment: Another catch phrase, but for more specific cases: (воевать) _не числом, а умением_. (А. В. Суворов)

Comment: Беня говорит мало, но он говорит смачно.

Comment: Definitely the best one, especially because it is by Lenin. Consice and euphonic.

Answer (score 6):

To modify a little V.V.'s suggestion

> Качество превыше количества

оr

> Главное не количество, а качество
>   Не количество главное, а качество

Not sure if they're the best though.

Answer (score 4):

We usually say, "Качество превыше всего" (Quality is above everything ).
You can also say, "Я предпочитаю качество количеству".

Comment: "Качество превыше всего" doesn't explicitly mention quantity. The second one is cumbersome.

Answer (score -2):

The best and natural option is 
Количество переходит в качество.

Comment: This phrase is absurd in given context.